# How to delete large amount of records from a large table (NOT all the records ) without logging?

Tags: sql-server-2008, logging

I have a large table with 8,000,000 records.
I want to delete about 3,000,000 records from it without logging....

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384786/delete-sql-server-2005-records-without-logging

Comment: SQL Server will log all operations - you cannot turn that off.

Comment: Which recovery model do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you cannot stop the logging.

But during a delete of 3 Mio records, your log will massively increase. In that case, you should delete in small parts.

An alternative would be the reverse way: Store away the records you want to keep, than use `TRUNCATE TABLE`, then insert back the saved records.